# Minecraft Bukkit 1.8 saving list into config.yml

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have an arraylist of string-arrays and I want to save that into a config.yml.
So how can I do that?
I have absolutely no plan, how to save the list into the config.yml and read it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should read Bukkit's [Configuration API Reference,](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference) which will introduce you to getting and setting configuration items via YML files. Between that and this older post - [Bukkit's Yaml Configuration Tutorial](https://bukkit.org/threads/bukkits-yaml-configuration-tutorial.42770/) - you should be able to get a good handle on how to best approach your task. Or for a more generic approach, consider looking at Somov's [SnakeYAML Documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation), which is the library used by Bukkit/Spigot.